# undefined method `model_name' for Mailer - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make a contact me form in Rials 5 with the built in Mail features. 
I put it together a lot like a regular controller and views with a Mailer as the model. But when I have it all written out I get the error:

> undefined method `model_name' for #ContactMailer

Contact is the name of the Mailer. 
The error comes up when I try to view the new.html.erb page with rails server running. It looks like this:
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oeL7.png)

Here is the code I am working with:

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @contact = ContactMailer.new
end

def create
    @contact = ContactMailer.new(params[:name, :email, :message]) 
    if @contact.deliver
        flash[:success] = "Your message has been sent." 
    else
        flash[:error] = "There was a problem sending your message."
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

And

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', required: true %></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :message %>
            <%= f.text_area :message, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

            <%= f.submit "Send", class: 'btn btn-default' %> 

    <% end %>
```

There is also the generated Mailer and views, but I have not changed anything with those.

From what I have been able to research the error could be that I have not initialized the @contact variable, but I believe that I have. And now I am lost. Any help would be appreciated.

As additional information:
My plan is for this contact form to send an email using send grid on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a mailer.Thats not how they are used. They are not models.

Instead you would do something like:

```
 ContactMailer.some_method_you_added_to_your_mailer(params[:name, :email, :message]).deliver_now
```

You don't use new on them.

Suggest you read over http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html .